# Ruby On Rails 4.0 - Не загружается bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby, веб-программирование

Изучай Ruby on Rails по [Ruby On Rails Tutoral by Michaele Hartl](http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/filling-in-the-layout#top). Не могу установить bootstrap. Делаю все по учебнику:

1 - добавляю в `Gemfile`

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
```

2 - устанавливаю

```
$ bundle install
```

3 - добавляю в `application.rb`

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
```

4 - содаю файл `custom.css.scss` в `app/assets/stylesheets` и добавляю туда

```
@import "bootstrap";
```

Перезапускаю сервер, но страница не преобразовывается. Остается в таком виде[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код страницы:

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
<h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

<h2>
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  sample application.
</h2>

<%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
```

Код `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                       "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" =>             true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js">    </script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно переименовать `'app/assets/stylesheets/application.css'` в `'application.css.scss'` и в него уже написать:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Для работы с javacsript, надо в файл `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` добавить строки:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

Это всё написано в документации к гему https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Answer (score 0):

В начало файла `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` добавьте строку `@import 'custom';`, после всех `import`-ов

Comment: Вообще-то  `*= require_tree` в `application.scss` должно все добавить, `custom.css.scss` в том числе.

Comment: @PavelVolzhin тогда странно что не работает.